# pentaho data integration excel file outputs

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-data-integration

using the Pentaho ETL tool I am trying to get an SQL query result dumped into an excel file output. I have created an excel file and saved it but the transformation executes but does not update the excel file. I am trying to insert select * from table A into the excel file.

The connection to the database is fine as I have other transformations.
The two steps are execute SQL script which I have tested in isolation and works, the second is the Microsoft excel output which is not working.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Table input instead of Execute SQL script. Execute SQL script doesn't give output to next steps